# Cant fetch bucket items while accessing minio server from domain [Websocket error]

Tags: websocket, apache2, bucket, minio

When I am accessing server of minio directly from ip 159.XX.XXX.XX:9000
then it able to fetch items of bucket but are not been able to fetched while accessing from domain  inventory.vmplay.ml.conf
both files for apache configuration are :-
`  GNU nano 6.2                inventory.vmplay.ml.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName inventory.vmplay.ml

```
ProxyPass / http://159.223.90.95:9001/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) "ws://159.223.90.95:9001/$1" [P,L]
```

`and` <VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName inventory-api.vmplay.ml

```
ProxyPass / http://159.223.90.95:9000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://159.223.90.95:9000/
```

`